# GIT repository with subset of a main repository

Tags: git, ansible, continuous-integration

Currently I’m working on a POC for automation with Ansible and GIT. In this scenario I have:

- **one** blueprint repository with various config directories for different topics and/or devices
- **Multiple** customer repository’s - one for each customer I would like to copy a subset of directories from the blueprint repository to a customer repository - only the ones that are needed and not everything. The configs in the customer repositories from the blueprint won’t be edited or changed. Customer specific data/config will be provided with additional files.

Currently I accomplish this task with a python script.

And here is my problem:
When there is a change in the blueprint repository which is also present in one or more customer repositories the customers configs will be inconsistent from the blueprint repository.
Is there a way or tool to accomplishes the copy task form blueprint repository to a customer repository with selected files and or directories and also checks for changes in the blueprint repo and e.G. pushes the new config in a new branch to the customer repo?

I already had a look at git submodules which is in my opinion not suitable since I would need to create a separate repository for each config directories to link it as a submodule - which could reach upto nearly one hundred and more in the future.

Also git subtree would not be a suitable solution, because a subtree would only allow me to insert a copy of the whole blueprint repository as a subdirectory to a customer repository but not only specific directories from the blueprint repo.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

What you need is simply a CI system with templatized configurations. In short it will work as follows:

1. You will create certain configuration templates as 'blueprints' in your central repository.
2. You will maintain this repository by patching it simply in the way you are doing right now.
3. You will setup your CI system with pipelines, where whenever you push a change to your central repository (blueprint), customer repositories are pulled in, and tested one by one to check for regression.
4. Once the test succeeds, you will have another `publish` pipeline, that will generate automated PRs to your customer repositories with this new change automatically.
5. As a bonus, you can setup a CI in customer repositories as well, where every incoming change from upstream (blueprint) will trigger a pipeline where all the configuration items in the current repo are "regenerated" and patched.

There are multiple CI solution that you can use and have this functionality. I suppose the easiest to start would be `GitHubActions CI`. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/features/actions).

Comment: Hi, looks like this is the way to go. I couldn' test it so far but I will provide you a feedback as soon as I can. Thank you very much for your help!